# Prevent accessing non-existant element from failing test

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

In an application that only contains a table view with 20 rows, all of them contains the text "Cell X", X being the index of the row, I have the following test:

```
func testTwentyFirstRow()
{
    let cell = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Cell 20"]
    let label = cell.label  
    XCTAssert(label == "Cell 20", "Label is not equal to Cell 20")
}
```

This tests fails on the second line with the following error

```
No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"Cell 20" IN identifiers' from input {(
    StaticText, 0x60800019b930, traits: 8589934656, label: 'Cell 0',
    ...
    StaticText, 0x60800019d740, traits: 8589934656, label: 'Cell 19'
)}
```

Is there any to prevent it to fail there but have it fail on the next line instead where I assert the value of the label?

Answer (score 0):

If you access a property of an XCUIElement other than `exists`, the framework will attempt to resolve the query which leads to the element and then inspect it to find the value of the property.

If you check an element `exists` before inspecting anything else or interacting with it, you can handle the case where it doesn't exist yet.

```
if cell.exists {
    let label = cell.label
    XCTAssertEqual(label, "text")
} else {
    XCTFail("Cell did not exist")
}
```

You don't have to fail the test at this point, you could take action to make the cell exist using a loop to keep scrolling until it does exist, or whatever you prefer.

Comment: But since `cell.exists` and `cell.label` are executed on different states of the application it's possible that when cell.label is execute the cell doesn't exist anymore. I might have oversimplified my problem with this table view example though. My real problem is that I have a video player that disappears when the video finishes playing and that makes my test fail.

Comment: It should be a near-instant check as the same snapshot will be used to check exists and label. Can you make the video longer to stabilise the test? Alternatively, label-checking tests work well as unit tests, where you can mock the entities which aren't under test.